# Alert message after add product

Tags: commerce, status-messages

I am using Drupal 7 and the Commerce module.

How can I set the alert message after adding a product in Drupal Commerce.

Comment: What exactly you mean by alert? JS popup? Landing page? In-page message? And who is supposed to be alerted? User who added (and supposedly knows what he's doing anyway)? Admin (who may be afk at the time)? Please clarify. Oh, and what have you tried so far? Maybe you're almost there already, and even if not, that could describe your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a callback in your submission .. something like this:

```
        YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'YourFormID') {
          $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_function';
        }
}

        function custom_submit_function($form, &$form_state) {
          drupal_set_message('ALERT MSG HERE');
        }
```

this [drupal_set_message()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) would give you the normal drupal message

if you don't know how to know your form ID ,, just print $form_id inside **hook_form_alter()** you'll see it there so you can make your if condition depending on it.

Comment: Only this code is working  for display the alert message ? you write here YOURMODULE_form_alter but how can i know which form is alter after write this code.

Comment: @PriyankPrajapati: you need to check for the form_id.I have updated my answer below.

Comment: I just edited the form_id condition to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In add product form, their will be a form_id, use that to differentiate to display message in that form alone.

```
hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'custom_add_user_form'){
         $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit_handler';  
    }
}



function custom_submit_handler(&$form, &$form_state){
   drupal_set_message('your message');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the "Add to cart confirmation" module that was created for Commerce Kickstart 2 :)

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_confirmation

Answer (score 0):

If you are uncomfortable with writing custom code, I use [commerce ajax add to cart](https://www.drupal.org/project/dc_ajax_add_cart) for this functionality.

They provide installation instructions in the README.md file.

You can configure the pop up message through the UI @ `admin/commerce/config/ajax-cart`, and also customize it with css. There are also a couple of blocks created for a teaser to go in your top bar, and another cart display. There are a couple of little quirks, and i think some patches in the github repository for this module, but we use this module in production, and have had great results with it. There are a couple of other ajax add to cart modules for D7, but i found commerce ajax add to cart to be a great addition!